XML error when adding remote WMS connection in Geoserver
I'm running GeoServer 2.25.3 and GeoTools 31.3 and I'm getting an error when trying to add a remote WMS connection to https://services.nconemap.gov/secure/services/Imagery/Orthoimagery_2020/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities and the connection doesn't save.
Here are some of the relevant snippets I extracted from the logs:
    ERROR  [geotools.xml] - Should not have any children - this is a simpleType    org.geotools.xml.handlers.SimpleElementHandler.getHandler(SimpleElementHandler.java:70)
    WARN   [geotools.xml] - org.xml.sax.SAXException: Should not have any children - this is a simpleType
    WARN   [geotools.xml] - Line 62 Col 45
    ERROR  [data.ows] - Failed to execute request https://services.nconemap.gov/secure/services/Imagery/Orthoimagery_2020/ImageServer/WMSServer?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.3.0&SERVICE=WMS

    org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Exception 'Can't overwrite cause with org.xml.sax.SAXException: Should not have any children - this is a simpleType' occurred during validation org.geoserver.web.data.store.WMSStoreNewPage$WMSCapabilitiesURLValidator on component 14:form:capabilitiesURL:border:border_body:paramValue
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Should not have any children - this is a simpleType at Line 62 Col 45 tag is: 
    div
    org.xml.sax.SAXException: Should not have any children - this is a simpleType
        at org.geotools.xml.XMLSAXHandler.startElement(XMLSAXHandler.java:419)
        ... 170 more

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Should not have any children - this is a simpleType
    at org.geotools.xml.handlers.SimpleElementHandler.getHandler(SimpleElementHandler.java:70)
    at org.geotools.xml.XMLSAXHandler.startElement(XMLSAXHandler.java:397)
    ... 170 more

I can consume this WMS service just fine in QGIS and ArcGIS Pro. On an older version of GeoServer (2.13.4), I get an XML error when trying to add the connection but I'm given the option to "save anyway".
It's unclear if this WMS service is actually serving invalid XML or not, but does anyone know if there is a way to bypass XML validation or forcibly save the connection?

Use the contact info that is found in <ContactElectronicMailAddress> and ask them to fix the layer abstract in the GetCapabilities.

It is invalid XML - the HTML in the abstract should be either plain text or inside a CDATA block to hide it from the parser.
While you are waiting for the problem to be fixed by the owner you could make a local copy and edit the abstract and point GeoServer at it using a file:// connection, though for me it's quiet slow and times out sometimes.

If GeoServer parses the GetCapabilities, the  static copy should also hold the self referencing URL@ /WMS_Capabilities/Capability[1]/Request[1]/GetCapabilities[1]/DCPType[1]/HTTP[1]/Get[1]/OnlineResource[1]/@*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' and local-name()='href']

GeoServer is smart enough to never (I think) use the GetCapabilities in the capabilities in the file to look for the capabilities. It will use all the other values.
